# Additional field added to Firebase and not updating correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Every time I answer the first question of the assessment I get an empty string added (as an option) as well as the option that was selected and I'm not sure where this is coming from. Also when Firebase is updated, if the string matches another string, for example 'Yes' is selected for more than one question, it only appears the first time in Firebase. I would prefer the option number to show anyway instead of the option string so it shows 'option1' instead of 'Yes, completely'. How would I fix these issues?

Ideally, I would like to update Firebase with the question and below it which option number was selected for that question.

[image]

```
Future<void> update(Map data) {
    return ref.setData(Map<String, dynamic>.from(data), merge: true);
  }


Future<void> update(Map data) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    Document<T> ref = Document(path:  '$collection/${user.uid}');
    return ref.update(data);
  }
```

```
Future<void> _updateUserReportWithQuestion(Questions questions, Options optionSelected) {
  return Global.reportRef.update(
    ({
      'questions': {
      'questions': FieldValue.arrayUnion([questions.text]),
      'options': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
        optionSelected.option1, 
        optionSelected.option2, 
        optionSelected.option3, 
        optionSelected.option4, 
        optionSelected.option5,
        ]),
      },
})
```

Comment: what is 'upsert'? Also, looks like your code is missing some ) and }.
Can you also add the code where you call this method?

Comment: In the [documentation][1] you can see that is added just the elements that not exists, so if you have two 'Yes' in your array will be added just one.


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: `upsert` isn't a method provided by the Firestore SDK.  Please edit the question to show more clearly what it is doing.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: I think there are still some extra commas at the last lines.